# c# decimal Tryparse from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get a decimal out of a string for instance "3.8 lkjhdf" how can I get just the 3.8 out. This needs to be dynamic cause it could be "333333.8 kljsdf"

```
if (!double.TryParse(parsedText, out measurment))
{
    string measurmentString = Regex.Match(parsedText, @"\d+").Value;
    if (double.TryParse(parsedText, out measurment))
    { 
    }
}
paramaterText3.Add(measurment);
```

Comment: `string.Split()` on the space character?  Regular expression to pull out valid numbers?

Comment: Note that your inner TryParse is still going on the parsedText value, which you already know to be invalid. Identify and use the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be: `\d+(\.\d+)?`  and you should use the `measurmentString` in your second `double.TryParse` attempt:

```
if (!double.TryParse(parsedText, out measurment))
{
    string measurmentString = Regex.Match(parsedText, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value;
    if (double.TryParse(measurmentString , out measurment))
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to delimit the period else it would match anything.

Comment: What if the number is only one digit ? x)

Comment: was just updating for that :-)

Comment: Just a change on the lastest + for a * would have done the work. But this is nice too. ^^

Comment: Thanks been searching for this for a while seen plenty of posts but couldn't find the right one.